Python implementation of Label Ranking Trees
Label Ranking is a classification task in which there is a set of potential labels; given a feature vector, the classifier should decide how to rank the labels from most-relevant to least-relevant. As an example, given an image, the classifier should decide what object is the most prominent, second-most prominent, etc.
There are several label ranking algorithms in Weka; they are based on works by Fürnkranz, Hüllermeier and others. One of the common algorithms is called LRT - Label Ranking Trees. Is there any implementation for this algorithm, or for another ranking algoritm, in Python?
